# absolute position of link element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

I write a jquery to find absolute position of each link element like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[href]").each(function(){
    var x = $(this).offset().left;
    var y = $(this).offset().top;
    ......
  });
});
```

However, if it doesn't work on links that you could only see once you hover your mouse to its container. For example, on page of http://illinois.edu, There is a link called "Future Students". If you hover your mouse there, there are more links pop up, one is "Undergraduate Admissions", but this link will give me x = 0 and y = 0 while the "Furture Students" one give me the correct position. Some other examples like http://web.cs.toronto.edu/, there are links pop up form the top green bar. Those links will give me  y = some negative numbers. So how could I get absolute position of these "pop up links"? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If link's are hidden (*`display:none`*), you will not be able to get their position -

From the [API](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

> Note: jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden
>   elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the
>   body element.
>
> While it is possible to get the coordinates of elements with
>   visibility:hidden set, display:none is excluded from the rendering
>   tree and thus has a position that is undefined.

Comment: I see,thanks. So even I don't use jquery, I still will not be able to get the position of these links, right?

Comment: How do you get the position of visibility:hidden element?